# What's the answer of ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} (2x+5) \ln( \sqrt{x^2 + 3} + x + 1) }$?

Tags: limits

What's the answer of ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} (2x+5) \ln( \sqrt{x^2 + 3} + x + 1) }$?

I used Wolfram alpha and got $-3$, but I don't know the steps. Can anyone teach me the steps?

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to solve this is to do the Taylor expansion of the logarithm, and before that, of the square root. Are you familiar with those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes many tricks. First, we write the function into the following form:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{(2x+5)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x+1)}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\ln\left[(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x+1)^{2x+5}\right]}.$$

Instead we consider the limit of $(1+x+\sqrt{x^2+3})^{2x+5}$ as $x\to-\infty$.

We can observe that it has the form $1^\infty$, so furthermore we also consider the limit of $(2x+5)(x+\sqrt{x^2+3})$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{(2x+5)(x+\sqrt{x^2+3})}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\frac{(2x+5)\cdot 3}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-x}}=3\cdot\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\frac{2x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-x}}.$$

Now we substitute $x:=-y$ and then

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\frac{2x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+3}-x}}=\lim_{y\to\infty}{\frac{5-2y}{\sqrt{y^2+3}+y}}=\lim_{y\to\infty}{\frac{5/y-2}{\sqrt{1+3/y^2}+1}}=\frac{-2}{2}=-1.$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{(2x+5)(x+\sqrt{x^2+3})}=3\cdot(-1)=-3,$$

which follows

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{(1+x+\sqrt{x^2+3})^{2x+5}}=e^{-3}$$

and hence

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{(2x+5)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x+1)}=\ln(e^{-3})=-3.$$

Comment: Thank you. This trick is new to me.

Comment: Could you write out the theorem you used, something like $\lim f^g = \exp \lim (f-1)g$ when $f \to 1$ and $g \to \infty$ and the limits exist?

Answer (score 1):

I would first substitute $y = -x$ to get the equivalent

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}(-2y+5)\ln(\sqrt{y^2 + 3} - y + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, extract a $y$ factor and then use [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) on the square root term to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{y^2 + 3} - y + 1 & = y\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{y^2}}\right) - y + 1 \\
& = y\left(1 + \frac{3}{2y^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^4}\right)\right) - y + 1 \\
& = y + \frac{3}{2y} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right) - y + 1 \\
& = 1 + \frac{3}{2y} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using \eqref{eq2A} and then the Taylor series for the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\ln\left(1 + \frac{3}{2y} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)\right) & = \frac{3}{2y} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, you have from \eqref{eq1A} that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}(-2y+5)\ln(\sqrt{y^2 + 3} - y + 1) & = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}(-2y+5)\left(\frac{3}{2y} + O\left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\right) \\
& = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\left(-3 + O\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right) \\
& = -3
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=-\frac1x$. Then,

$$L=
{\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} (2x+5) \ln( \sqrt{x^2 + 3} + x + 1) }
= { \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (-\frac2t+5) \ln( \sqrt{\frac1{t^2 }+ 3} -\frac1t + 1) }
$$

Note

$$\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac1{t^2 }+ 3} -\frac1t + 1\right)
=\ln\left( \frac1t(1+\frac32t^2+O(t^3)) -\frac1t + 1) \right)\\
=\ln\left( 1+\frac32t+O(t^2))  \right)=\frac32t+O(t^2)
$$

Thus,

$$L= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (-\frac2t+5)(\frac32t+O(t^2))
= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (-3+O(t))=-3
$$